# Formality: "city" people vs "city"er vs the people of "city" vs "city"'s populace

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice, phrase-usage

How would you rank the following phrases, which more or less describe the same thing, from most to least formal/precise (the chosen term will be used to describe the residents of a city):

1. London/New York people
2. Londoner/New Yorker
3. the people of London/New York
4. London/New York's populace

My ranking

Formality: 4 >= 3 >> 1 = 2; Precision: 4 >= 2 >= 3 >= 1

I've seen many instances of officials referring to residents of a city as Londoner/New Yorker. I suppose such use is recognised as semi-formal in the least?

Also, could someone explain if there's any differences in using these phrases?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: I'd say they all carry the same degree of accuracy ('New Yorker', for instance, being as ambiguous as 'the people of New York' – one assumes the state or city rather than the county of the same name is meant).'

Comment: How about formality? Which would be the most formal to you?

Comment: I'd say that 4 is so formal (and / or archaic) that it is almost always better avoided. 'Citizens of New York' is a good formal choice. / I think that 'Londoner' may well cover a broader range along the formal-informal continuum than 'New Yorker', but I'm only really very familiar with the former. 'The people of L/NY' is unmarked-to-becoming-conversational, while (1) is chatty.

Comment: I'll venture that while #1 is the least formal, it (almost?) refers to something different. The implication with London/New York people is not necessarily that the people live there but that they *fit* the city—they are the *kind* of people that live in NY/L, even if they don't, or they are the people that do live there and really embody the city—whereas others could live there and not embody the city

Comment: A Londoner doesn't necessarily live in London, and the population of London aren't necessarily all Londoners.

Answer (score 1):

There is no question of formality. The examples each mean something different.

City people are people in general who either come from or now live in and feel part of  City

A Cityer is one person who either comes from or now lives in and feels part of  City

The people of City are all the people who now live in City, considered as a collection of individuals

City’s populace is all the people who now live in City, considered as a crowd; effectively, as a swarm